# How to comment on an Elasticsearch index mapping?

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

As I create an index used by a larger team, I need to document basics like the date, time, author, scope, etc.

Is there a comment field I can use besides the too-exposed index name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`_meta` field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-meta-field.html) in the mapping to add any custom information that suits your index.

```
PUT my-index-000001
{
  "mappings": {
    "_meta": { 
      "date": "2023-05-17",
      "time": "10:12",
      "author": "John Doe",
      "scope": "Development"
    }
  }
}
```

The `_meta` field can be updated on an existing type using the update mapping API:

```
PUT my-index-000001/_mapping
{
  "_meta": {
    "date": "2023-05-18",
    "time": "23:10",
    "author": "Jane Doe",
    "scope": "Quality"
  }
}
```

Comment: BTW, can this be edited after the index creation?
PS: Yes, it can, it's in the documentation, should have checked

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped! Yes you can edit the metadata after the index creation simply by updating the mapping with `PUT index/_mapping`